# Are there fat-tailed distributions with FINITE variance and defined moments?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) seems like there shouldn't be.

The only example I studied was the Cauchy distribution, which indeed has fat tails, but also undefined moments, and hence variance. Is there any distribution with tails fatter than normal distribution (but still the same "bell shape")?

Comment: What is the definition of fat tail? One definition of fat tail could be just so that variance escapes finity.

Comment: Hmm, I just answered and then deleted my answer about the Pareto distribution since I oversaw your comment about asking for bell-shaped distributions.

Comment: @Therkel: If you reflect the distribution about x=0 to obtain a symmetrical distribution, would that count as bell-shaped?

Comment: @Rahul that would have been a nice and easy. However, I suspected the $t$-distribution was fat tailed so I edited the answer to use that distribution instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fat-tailed distribution is a distribution for which the tail behaves like a power law, i.e.

$$F(x) \sim 1- x^{-\alpha}$$
for $x\to \infty $ and some $\alpha>0$. Equivalently

$$
f(x) \sim x^{-\alpha-1}, \quad x\to \infty, \quad \alpha>0,
$$
where $f$ is the pdf.

---

The density of the student $t$-distribution can be written as 
$$
f(x) = C_1(1+x^2/\nu)^{-(\nu+1)/2}, \quad \nu > 0,
$$
where $C_1$ is the normalization constant in the pdf.

Asymptotically $(1+cx^a)^b \sim c^bx^{ab}$, $x\to \infty$ for some constants $a>0,b,c\in \mathbb R$ so
$$
f(x) \sim C_1(x^2/\nu)^{-(\nu+1)/2} = C_2 \lvert x\rvert ^{-\nu-1}, \quad x\to \pm \infty
$$
for some other constant $C_2$ ($C_2$ absorbed $\nu^{(\nu+1)/2}$). That means that the $t$-distribution is fat-tailed.

As we know, the student $t$-distribution has finite variance if $\nu>2$ and has moments up to order $\nu$. Hence:

#### Yes, fat-tailed bell-shaped distributions with finite variance exist.

Comment: As confirmation of this with $\nu=3$ degrees of freedom (so finite variance $3$)  try the R statements `plot(log(1:100), pt(1:100, df=3, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = TRUE))` and `plot(log(1:100), dt(1:100, df=3, log = TRUE))` and spot how the pattern is close to linear

Comment: This definition of "fat-tailed" is  restrictive and misleading. The insistence on infinite support is not necessary, nor is the insistence on the exponential power law.  Alternative definitions of "fat tailedness," such as moment and quantile kurtosis, are also viable. See my post below for a useful counterexample: In my post, I give an extremely heavy-tailed distribution that would presumably be called "light-tailed" using the power law definition.

Answer (score 3):

Often, "fat-tailed" is synonymous with "outlier-prone." You can have outlier-prone distributions with finite tails, hence all moments finite.

For example, mix a U(-1,1) with a U(-10000, 10000), with .0001 mixing probability on the latter.  Here is some R code that simulates 1000000 such observations, calculates the extreme Z values, and the kurtosis.

set.seed(12345)

N = 1000000

p = .0001

U0 = runif(N)

U1 = runif(N,-1,1)

U2 = runif(N, -10000, 10000)

X = ifelse(U0 > p, U1, U2)

sort.Z =sort(scale(X))

head(sort.Z)

tail(sort.Z)

kurt <- function(y) {

n = length(y)

p = rep(1/n,n)

ey = sum(y*p)

vy = sum((y-ey)^2*p)

sdy = sqrt(vy)

kurt = sum( ((y-ey)/sdy)^4 *p) -3

return(kurt)

}

kurt(X)

Kurtosis is the average of the Z-values, each taken to the fourth power. Extreme Z-values, like here, indicate outliers. The extreme Z-values printed by the code above are

-163.9421 -158.7251 -155.8845 -154.8858 -154.3153 -153.1298

and

148.0770 148.1702 159.8075 161.1619 163.0165 164.8768

Observations greater than 100 standard deviations from the mean, as in this example, are commonly called "outliers."

The kurtosis printed from the code above is of course high as well: 16094.69.

Notice that the distribution is perfectly flat at its "peak," providing a good counterexample to the incorrect notion that high kurtosis corresponds to a "peaked", or "pointy" distribution.